# apache mpm-worker (Module mpm_worker does not exist!)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, mpm-worker

I am newbie and I have Ubuntu 12.04 box where I installed Apache using command

```
apt-get install apache2
```

It installed everything fine. Then I needed mpm-worker so I installed mpm-worker using command

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
```

But when I want to enable module I got this error:

```
ERROR: Module mpm_worker does not exist!
```

I am not able to find these modules in mods-available directory. I searched but did not find anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Multi-Processing Modules are part of Apache 2.2, and are included with the apache2 install. You just need to "switch" from whatever MPM you are currently using to the worker MPM. **NOTE: You can ONLY start Apache with a single MPM selected, i.e. you MUST "dismod" the current and then "enmod" the desired**.

To determine which MPM is currently in use, run `apache2ctl -V`. You will see a line such as:

```
 Server MPM:     prefork
```

Assuming that you are running "prefork" (as in the above example), the switch is made with the following commands:

```
 a2dismod mpm_prefork
 a2enmod mpm_worker
 service apache2 restart
```

NOTE: If you are not logged in as root (and you should NOT be!), you will probably need to preface each command line with `sudo` to have sufficient privileges.